# Open .html file on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox

I have a dropbox public link like this:
https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xxxxxx/index.html
I want to open it on iPhone and it should be shown the content of html like this.

[image]

But the actual result was:
[image]

I don't know why. Can anyone help me !!!

Comment: let us know what kind of difficulties do you have

Comment: You should be able to host your html properly in order to make it render proper in browser. Try out my solution, I have used the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see that your aim is to make IPA download on clicking specific link.

What I did was, created new repository over GitHub and uploaded index.html over there.

Then I followed steps mentioned [here](https://pages.github.com)

Steps to host on Github.

1. Create a new project.
2. Add index.html as we will be hosting a site in
   Github Pages. Note html file with other name will not be valid as it
   should always be with index name.
3. Now go to project settings. Traverse through Github Pages
4. Under source tab select master-branch and click on save
5. Traverse back Github Pages you will see site will be published

It will show the html page as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your link in SFSafariViewController. Use below code to open:

```
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "your dropbox link")!)
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Don't forget to `import SafariServices` in your view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You also can load external URL in WKWebview and also in SFSafariViewController

```
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url =  NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com") else { return }
        webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: url as URL) as URLRequest)
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }
```